# mysql TRIGGER reject INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

so i have a mysql table with two attributes:  str, num

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(str VARCHAR(25) not null, num INT not null);
```

and i want both 'str' and 'num' to be filled in for every INSERT.
For example

```
INSERT INTO tbl(str)
VALUES('my_str')
```

this does not insert num and i want the trigger to reject the above INSERT statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

...i'm lost here

END
```

How should such a TRIGGER be constructed? Many thanks for help.

Comment: Since both columns are set to not null, the insert should fail without a trigger.

Comment: Specifically, both columns are set to `NOT NULL` with no default value.  An insert with only one column will fail without need for a trigger.

Comment: yes, but i would like to know how to do it with a trigger.

Comment: 'not null' is a bandaid for what i'm trying to do

Comment: i came across this comment                                                                                                  Generally the way to do this is to have some field in the table set to not null, and then in the trigger set that field to NULL.